bash tab completion doesn't work with source
When there's executables in my ~/bin folder, I can usually type part of it, for example "my_", and then hit tab so it auto completes to become "my_executable". However, when sourcing, e.g., typing ". my_", then tab complete doesn't work.
How can I get this to work?
